# Changing Y axis to percent with grouped bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a bar plot in ggplot that is a count of the number each of species observed along a transect at 3 different treatment levels. This is my data set:

```
df <- structure(list(Species = c("DOL", "STAR", "LOB", "DOL", "STAR", "URCH", "DOL", "STAR", "RCRAB", "DOL", "LOB", "STAR", "DOL", "DOL", "DOL", "RCRAB", "STAR", "STAR", "DOL", "RCRAB", "DOL", "STAR", "RCRAB", "CUNN", "CUNN", "CUNN", "FLOU", "CUNN", "FLOU", "CUNN", "FLOU", "CUNN", "CUNN", "FLOU", "FLOU", "CUNN"), Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Control Site", "Reef", "Reef Adjacent"), class = "factor"), Count = c(108L, 78L, 12L, 108L, 78L, 21L, 108L, 78L, 69L, 108L, 12L, 78L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 69L, 78L, 78L, 108L, 69L, 108L, 78L, 69L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 34L, 91L, 34L, 91L, 34L, 91L, 91L, 34L, 34L, 91L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), groups = structure(list(Species = c("CUNN", "DOL", "FLOU", "LOB", "RCRAB", "STAR","URCH"), .rows = structure(list(c(24L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 36L), c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 19L, 21L), c(27L, 29L, 31L, 34L, 35L), c(3L, 11L), c(9L, 16L, 20L, 23L), c(2L, 5L, 8L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 22L), 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I have been using this code to create my bar graph:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Species, fill=Treatment)) + 
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(0.9), width=0.8) + 
theme_bw() + 
ylab("Number of transects") + 
ggtitle("Species observed per transect per treatment")
```

[image]

Instead of having a count on the y axis, I'd like to have a percentage. I have tried a few different lines of code but can only come up with a percentage of the entire data set, but I need the percentages grouped by treatment. Can someone make a suggestion? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You could pre calculate the percentage per `group_by` on Treatment and use `geom_col` to use the pct values with a percentage axis using `percent` from `scales` package like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df |>
  group_by(Treatment) |>
  mutate(pct = Count/sum(Count)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, fill=Treatment, y = pct)) + 
  geom_col(position=position_dodge(0.9), width=0.8) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  ylab("Number of transects") + 
  ggtitle("Species observed per transect per treatment") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't think this is correct. For example, the species DOL is present on all 3 transects (y value) for all 3 treatments. So the percentage for each treatment level should be 100%. Another example, URCH- present on 1/3 transects, meaning the percentage should be 33%.